# Applying image textures - Bump, Displacement, Opc?

Tags: rendering, shaders, displacement, bump

I have an .obj file that I'm trying to place in Blender (see attached pic), and I'm a bit confused about the three image textures contained in the download file. There are three files labeled:

1. gummy_bum (bump)
2. gummy_disp (displacement)
3. gummy_opc (don't know what this means?)

I gather that the bump and displacement can be sort of blended into the output, but I'm not exactly sure how to do that. More importantly, I have no idea what 'opc' is referring to, or where to plug that in, and that is the little sugar granules on the gummy. Any ideas on how I should set this up in the shader?

[image]

Comment: OPC -> Opacity?

Comment: Could be, thx. Just not sure what to do with that haha

Comment: I'd say it's similar to the alpha setting

Comment: Yeah, but when I plug it into the alpha, it makes those areas of the object transparent, so that doesn't seem to get the effect of the sample render here (sugar coating)